# How to append a row which contains a value into another array using numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm trying to extract certain rows from an array into another array if a value in the array is greater than 4. The original array comes from a star catalog looking like this: 
[image: Catlog]

my attempt at a solution:

```py
for i in catalog:
    if catalog[i][:,11]>=4:            #
        bad_ones.append(i)



print(bad_ones)
```

Where catalog is a file that has been imported using

```py
catalog=np.loadtxt("catalog.cat", comments="#", unpack=False, ndmin=2)
```

However I receive this error: IndexError: arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type for line with a #
I've tried without the [i] after if lines but i get ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

I want to iterate through the rows and check if the value in the 12th column is greater than or equal to 4 and then append that row to another array. So for example, in the image, 1st row 12th column has a value of 16 so that whole row would be appeneded to a new array called bad_ones.

Comment: can you please provide a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Read what MVCE is and tried to make it easier to understand the problem, cheers.